# "The terminal process "/usr/local/bin/bash '-l'" terminated with exit code: 1."

Tags: .net, bash, visual-studio-code, terminal, exit-code

When I open the bash terminal in VScode it immediately closes and I get the following error: "The terminal process "/usr/local/bin/bash '-l'" terminated with exit code: 1.". I have looked everywhere for this instance and I am still clueless what it might be.
[image]

I have tried to change some terminal settings in VScode as well as trying to figure out if anything is wrong with my terminal, but I'm just not familiar with the terminal.

Comment: What OS are you running VScode in?

Comment: @amphetamachine macOS version Sonoma 14.2.1